# Is it possible to write 'else if' N times with for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement

I'm writing an entab program which is K&R exercise.

> Exercise 1-21. Write a program **entab** that replaces strings of blanks by the minimum number of tabs and blanks to achieve the same spacing.

My solution is dividing each line by N character(`where 1 tab == N whitespace`) and checking from the rightmost character to the first character whether it is whitespace character or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void entab(int n);

int main(void)
{
    entab(8);
}

void entab(int n) // n should be at least 2
{
    int c;
    int i, j;
    int temp[n];

    while (1) {

        // Collect n characters
        // If there is EOF, print all privious character and terminate the while loop.
        // If there is new line character, print all privious and current character, then continue the while loop again.
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            temp[i] = getchar();
            if (temp[i] == EOF) {
                if (i > 0)
                    for (j = 0; j < i; ++j)
                        putchar(temp[j]);
                break;
            }
            else if (temp[i] == '\n') {
                for (j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
                    putchar(temp[j]);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (temp[i] == EOF)
            break;
        if (temp[i] == '\n')
            continue;

        // the temp array has exactly 8 characters without newline character and EOF indicator.
        // check a continuity of the whitespace character and put the tab character at the right space.
        if (temp[n-1] != ' ') {
            for (i = 0; i <= n-1; ++i)
                putchar(temp[i]);
        }
        for (j = n-2; j >= 0; --j) {
            else if (temp[j] != ' ') {
                for (i = 0; i <= j; ++i)
                    putchar(temp[i]);
                putchar('\t');
            }
        }
        else
            putchar('\t');
    }
}
```

This part makes sense but is syntactically not allowed. But I have to use a loop syntax because I want the program to entab a arbitrary number of the whitespace character.

```
if (temp[n-1] != ' ') {
    for (i = 0; i <= n-1; ++i)
        putchar(temp[i]);
}
for (j = n-2; j >= 0; --j) {
    else if (temp[j] != ' ') {
        for (i = 0; i <= j; ++i)
            putchar(temp[i]);
        putchar('\t');
    }
}
else
    putchar('\t');
```

I tried a function-like macro but it didn't make significant difference. Is it just impossible?  Should I consider another design or logic?

Comment: Why do you need `else if` when there is no `if` before that? Just use `if`.

Comment: @Barmar Because I want to use `else if` in for loop as if they were logically connected with above `if`. Then if the first `if` statement meets its condition, following `else if` and `else` will be ignored.

Comment: Why don't you just put the entire 2nd loop in an `else` block?

Comment: `else { for (j = ...) ...}`

Comment: Your `for ... else` sounds like a `while` with reversed condition. (But a `while` ca't have an `else` either, so you must wrap tat ito an `if .. else`.)

Comment: @Barmar I think that is good point I didn't aware. But main problem is that if we use if statement in for loop, each if statement is always executed because we can't use `else if` in for loop. They won't be logically connected. I want to use `if ... else if ... else if ... else if ... // else if ... N times // else` this structure where N is arbitrary constant.

Comment: "Should I consider another design or logic?" -- That seems like a good idea. Reading the initial string in chunks of n bytes, no matter whether they are spaces or not, does not look right. Instead, copy all non-spaces verbatim and keep the current position on the line. If you see a stretch of two or more spaces, determine how you can turn them into tabs. Reset the position on a new line. (And usually, a tab is not just replaced by n spaces; it makes a gap, so that the next character appears at a multiple of n.)

Comment: @MOehm I think you suggested starting from the first character of a chunk(my method was starting from the last). I'll try that. Thank you.

Comment: Your problem is that your chunks are just any characters. The tabwidth should come into play only once you have seen more than one space in a row. And when reading from a stream with `getchar()`, starting at the beginning makes sense, doesn't it. `:)`